# Python+bottle ошибка invalid syntax при import requests в одном месте есть, в другом нет

Tags: python, bottle

Имею установленный на сервере питон и фреймворк bottle

```
    import os, sys
    import requests
    sys.path.append('/home/s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests')
    from bottle import default_app, route, run, debug, request, view, static_file
    from bottle import *
    
    @route('/')
    def default():
        return u'Hello Bottle!'
    
    @route('/no')
    def hello_world():
        return u'Hello ОТ - no -- Bottle!'
    
    @route('/c')
    def hello_world():
        return u'c Hello ОТ - -- Bottle!'
        
        
        
    @route('/age-form')
    @view('age-form')
    def age_form():
        pass
    
    @route('/age-result', method='POST')
    @view('age-result')
    def age_result():
        first_name = request.forms.get('name')
        api_result = requests.get('https://api.agify.io/?name=' + first_name)
        print(api_result)
        agify_data = api_result.json()
        return dict(
            name=first_name,
            age=agify_data['age']
        )
    
        
    
    #debug(True)
    application = default_app()
```

при выполнении получаю ошибку
[image: error]

однако тот же самый код вне фреймворка с той же библиотекой на том же сервере вполне работает. причем sys.path можно и закомментировать, все работает. в чем может быть причина?
рабочий код выполняемый из файла

```
    import os, sys
    import requests
    #sys.path.append('/home/s/shansokb/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests')
    api_result = requests.get('https://api.agify.io/?name=michael')
    agify_data = api_result.json()
    print(agify_data['age'])
```

Comment: Похоже, что вы выполняете код разными интерпретаторами в этих двух случаях. В том случае, когда не работает, используете python версии ниже чем 3.5, а версия библиотеки `charset_normalizer`, очевидно, не работает с такой старой версией питона. `sys.path можно и закомментировать` это тоже понятно, у вас requests установлен в том виртуальном окружении, которое вы используете с python 3.6/

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Роман спасибо! Проверила версию питон из директории, где все работает, там стоит 2.7. В неработающей же директории настраивался 3.6, обращение к 3.6 как раз видно в логах.  Локально у меня также стоит 3.6 и локально отрабатывает. Подскажите, это могут быть настройки сервера? Куда копать?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. С питоном 2.7 точно работать не может. Работать может только с питоном от 3.5 и выше. Объясните, что значит "питон настраивался в директории".

Comment: проблема пофикшена изменениями пути к питон интерпретатору в файле .htaccess